# Localized and ephemeral replies using Discord.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, localization

I've recently been playing a lot with localization on my Discord Bot, and I was wondering something.

When using localization, you can create a reply that uses different languages based of the user's language settings.

As seen in the code [here](https://discordjs.guide/slash-commands/response-methods.html#localized-responses) :

```js
client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, interaction => {
    const locales = {
        pl: 'Witaj Świecie!',
        de: 'Hallo Welt!',
    };
    interaction.reply(locales[interaction.locale] ?? 'Hello World (default is english)');
});
```

My problem is that I would like to do the same thing except using the ephemeral parameter, like so:

```js
await interaction.followUp({ content: 'Pong !', ephemeral: true });
```

But when I try to mix the two :

```js
async execute(interaction) {
    const locales = {
        pl: 'Witaj Świecie!',
    de: 'Hallo Welt!',
    };
    await interaction.reply(locales[interaction.locale] ?? 'Hello World!', ephemeral: true);
});
```

It doesn't work since the way you're supposed to write an ephemeral answer is like this:

```js
await interaction.followUp({ content: 'Pong again!', ephemeral: true });
```

So I was wondering if anyone had an idea, on how I could make the reply localized and ephemeral, and maybe change up my code so that it works.

That would be super helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close, you just need to add your content as the value of `content`:

```js
await interaction.reply({
  content: locales[interaction.locale] ?? 'Hello World!',
  ephemeral: true,
});
```

Your first example works because `reply` accepts a string as the content of the message.

```js
// ✅ works
interaction.reply(locales[interaction.locale] ?? 'Hello World (default is English)');
```

The second one doesn't work because you still pass a string as the first argument but if you want to use ephemeral messages, you need to pass an object instead of that string with a `content` and an `ephemeral` key.

```js
// ⛔️ doesn't work
await interaction.reply(
  locales[interaction.locale] ?? 'Hello World!',
  ephemeral: true
);

// ✅ works
await interaction.reply({
  content: locales[interaction.locale] ?? 'Hello World!',
  ephemeral: true,
});
```

Comment: That makes so much sense, putting it in a list like you did is so much more intelligible and understandable. Thanks a lot for that, you actually saved my day. And your makrdown and formatting on this answer look so cool. Thanks again!